# Django - Is there a difference between auth.models.User and .model.User (abstract)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

I have to import the User model in a file and I was wondering if there is any difference between the auth.models.User and an abstract user in .models.User:

> from django.contrib.auth.models import User

```
  or
```

> from .models import User

Answer (score 0):

The first one `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` is the standard extension of `AbstractUser` with no additional fields. Whereas your `from .models import User` is your customised `User` model that should also inherit from `AbstractUser` but has customisation for your Django project.

You can see what `django.contrib.auth.models` does in the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2fac0a18081dcc77fc860c801e5d727dc90435b3/django/contrib/auth/models.py).